# Get string from another string array if value matches

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

String Array 1: (In this format: `<MENU>|<Not Served?>|<Alternate item served>`)

```
Burger|True|Sandwich
Pizza|True|Hot Dog
```

String Array 2: (Contains Menu)

```
Burger
Pizza
Grill Chicken
Pasta
```

I need the menu is served or any alternate item served for that particular item.

Code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < strArr2.Length; i++)
{
    if(strArr2.Any(_r => _r.Split('|').Any(_rS => _rS.Contains(strArr1[i])))) 
    {
        var menu = strArr2[i];
        var alternate = ? // need to get alternate item
    }
}
```

As I commented in the code, how to get the alternate item in that string array? Please help, thanks in advance.

P.S: Any help to trim if condition is also gladly welcome.

Comment: What does each of the arrays represent?

Comment: First array represents only the Menu, and Alternate item served for that menu. Second array represents overall menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of any, you may use Where to get the value matching.

@Markus is having the detailed answer, I am just using your code to find a quick fix for you.

```
for(int i = 0; i < strArr2.Length; i++)
{
    if(strArr2.Any(_r => _r.Split('|').Any(_rS => _rS.Contains(strArr1[i])))) 
    {
        var menu = strArr2[i];
        var alternate = strArr2.Where(_rs => _rs.Split('|').Any(_rS => _rS.Contains(strArr1[i]))).First().Split('|').Last();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to simplify your code, it is a good idea to better separate the tasks. For instance, it will be much easier to handle the contents of string array 1 after you have converted the contents into objects, e.g.

```
class NotServedMenu
{
    public string Menu { get; set; }
    public bool NotServed { get; set; }
    public string AlternateMenu { get; set; }
}
```

Instead of having an array of strings, you can read the strings to a list first:

```
private IEnumerable<NotServedMenu> NotServedMenusFromStrings(IEnumerable<string> strings)
{
    return (from x in strings select ParseNotServedMenuFromString(x)).ToArray();
}

private NotServedMenu ParseNotServedMenuFromString(string str)
{
    var parts = str.Split('|');
    // Validate
    if (parts.Length != 3)
        throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Unable to parse \"{0}\" to an object of type {1}", str, typeof(NotServedMenu).FullName));
    bool notServedVal;
    if (!bool.TryParse(parts[1], out notServedVal))
        throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Unable to read bool value from \"{0}\" in string \"{1}\".", parts[1], str));
    // Create object
    return new NotServedMenu() { Menu = parts[0], 
                                 NotServed = notServedVal, 
                                 AlternateMenu = parts[2] }; 
}
```

Once you can use the objects, the subsequent code will be much cleaner to read:

```
var notServedMenusStr = new[] 
{
     "Burger|True|Sandwich", 
     "Pizza|True|Hot Dog"
};
var notServedMenus = NotServedMenusFromStrings(notServedMenusStr);
var menus = new[] 
{
     "Burger", 
     "Pizza", 
     "Grill Chicken", 
     "Pasta"
};
var alternateMenus = (from m in menus join n in notServedMenus on m equals n.Menu select n);
foreach(var m in alternateMenus)
    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}", m.Menu, m.NotServed, m.AlternateMenu);
```

In this sample, I've used a Linq join to find the matching items.

Comment: Explained in detail code and made me understand in easy way! Brilliant.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like that

```
string[] strArr1 = { "Burger|True|Sandwich", "Pizza|True|Hot Dog" };
string[] strArr2 = { "Burger", "Pizza", "Grill Chicken", "Pasta" };

foreach (string str2 in strArr2)
{
    string str1 = strArr1.FirstOrDefault(str => str.Contains(str2));
    if (str1 != null)
    {
        string[] splited = str1.Split('|');
        string first = splited[0];
        bool condition = Convert.ToBoolean(splited[1]);
        string second = splited[2];
     }
}
```

Comment: string str1 = strArr1.FirstOrDefault(str => str.Contains(str2)); //str1 is always null.